# An algorithm for animating a point over a closed path like square or triangle in canvas?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, animation, canvas

How to animate a point over a closed path. For the example below, I could pixel push this but I'm wondering if there is a better math(y) solution for animating over a path.

### **[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/text-path-travel-wxkdh)**

*Note: I'm using a `ctx.drawImg()` to represent the point because I'd like the point to rotate along the path (image below code).*

```
import "./styles.scss";
import o from "./letters/0.svg";

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const arena = 500;
const margin = 60;
const edge = arena - margin;

let data = [o];
var imgEls = [];

function drawArena() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = "3";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "DeepSkyBlue";
  const origin = [margin, margin];
  ctx.moveTo(...origin);
  ctx.lineTo(edge, margin);
  ctx.lineTo(edge, edge);
  ctx.lineTo(margin, edge);
  ctx.lineTo(...origin);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function loadImages() {
  return data.map((item, i) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      let img = new Image();
      let svg = new Blob([item], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(svg);
      img.onload = () => {
        imgEls.push(img);

        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        console.log("loaded");
        res(img);
      };
      img.src = url;
    });
  });
}

Promise.all(loadImages()).then(() => {
  // window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  draw();
});

function draw(t) {
  // window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  drawArena();
  imgEls.forEach((img, index) => {
    const offset = index * img.width;
    const x = margin + offset;
    const y = margin - img.height;

    ctx.drawImage(img, x, y);
  });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just tracking between 2 points; You're looking for Linear Interpolation.

Here's [what it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation):

> In mathematics, linear interpolation is a method of curve fitting using linear polynomials to construct new data points within the range of a discrete set of known data points.

[a demo](https://p5js.org/examples/math-linear-interpolation.html) in P5js

and a simple implementation in JS

```
function lerp(v0, v1, t) {
    return v0*(1-t)+v1*t
}
```

via https://github.com/mattdesl/lerp/blob/master/index.js

Tracking over a complex path is decidedly more complex. Let me know if you need that functionality and I'll see what I can dig up.